# Spinor covariant derivative conventions

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, conventions, dirac-equation, spinors

The covariant derivative of a spinor $\psi$ is given by

$$ \nabla_\mu \psi = \partial_\mu \psi + \Omega_\mu \psi $$

where $\Omega_\mu$ is the spin connection. In equation (7.227) of Geometry, Topology and Physics by Nakahara, the spin connection is given by $$\Omega_\mu = -\frac{1}{8} \omega_{\mu ab} [\gamma^a , \gamma^b].\tag{7.227}$$ However, in equation (8.35) of Freedman's Supergravity, the connection is given by $$\Omega_\mu = +\frac{1}{8} \omega_{\mu ab} [\gamma^a , \gamma^b].\tag{8.35}$$ Notice the sign difference. Now, this sign difference seems to make a difference when we take a covariant derivative of a gamma matrix. We expect that gamma matrices are covariantly constant:

$$ \nabla_\mu \gamma^\nu = \partial_\mu \gamma^\nu + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \alpha} \gamma^\alpha + [\Omega_\mu, \gamma^\nu ] =0$$

However, if I use Nakahara's convention, then this is not true anymore. Expanding the derivative explicitly in terms of the veilbein and spin connection, and using Nakahara's convention, we have

$$ \nabla_\mu \gamma^\nu =(\partial_\mu e^{\ \nu}_b + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \alpha}e^{\ \alpha}_b  +\omega^{\ a}_{\mu \ b} e_a^{\ \nu}) \gamma^b \quad (1)$$

Both authors define the spin connection as

$$ \omega_{\mu \ b}^{\ a} =e^a_{\ \nu} ( \partial_\mu e_b^{\ \nu} + \Gamma^\nu_{\mu \lambda} e_b^{\ \lambda} )$$

(Eq. (7.142) in Nakahara and (7.101) in Freedman) so we see that with Nakahara's definition, the derivative is not zero. However, if we took Freedman's definition, then the spin connection term in (1) would be negative, cancelling with the rest of the terms to yield $\nabla_\mu \gamma^\nu = 0$. I thought this may have something to do with the signature of the Minkowski metric being used, but both authors use the $(-,+,+,\ldots)$ convention.

Is the spin connection defined only up to a sign convention, and if so, does the definition of $\nabla_\mu \gamma^\nu $ depend upon this convention?

Comment: First thing I would check is the relation between the spin connection and the vielbein + Christoffel connection. This isn't a definition but rather derived from zero torsion and covariant constancy of the vielbein (and I think the minus sign should have an effect there).